# ASP.NET Core 5 development on macOS Big Sur - AD Authentication

Tags: macos, asp.net-core, active-directory

This is more of guidance question regarding ASP.NET Core 5.0 development on MacBook Pro Big Sur OS.
I want to build a React+ASP.NET Core 5.0 Web Site, For Authentication I've to build website with 2 alternatives, one to use Active Directory based and other alternative is to use  database users' entries to validate against.
Due to client's restrictions, I can't access their IT infra/AD information as I work remotely and I don't have permissions to install anything on their workstation. Once I've working demo with AD authentication, they'll engage their deployment team to port over my work in their test environment.

My doubts are around

1. how to setup AD authentication on my macbook so that I can use it for authentication?
2. how to have dual authentication i.e. AD in case users want it or database users' profile based.

My Visual Studio, Code, .NET etc are all working fine, I'm stuck in authorization part. I tried many articles but information is making me circle around, pardon my lack of Knowledge, it's been a while since ASP.NET development on all windows infra.